# Data pass to codeigniter to ajax the function not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I try to pass a data code igniter controller to ajax request the written function not working

Controller

```
public function selectPlaygrounds() {
    $data = $this->branchatm->getCitiesFromState($state);
    $result='';
    if($data){
        foreach($data as $list){
            $result.="<li ng-click='sawAll($list->city);'>$list->city</li>";
        }
    }
    sendJsonResponse($result);  
}
```

Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': base_url +'Ground/selectPlaygrounds', 
    success: function(data) {
        var newData = data.replace(/\"/g, "")
        if(newData == ""){
        }else{
             $("#ls-city-grnd").html(newData);
        }
    }
});
```

Here result show in browser network tab

```
<li ng-click='sawAll(North Goa);'>North Goa</li>
<li ng-click='sawAll(South Goa);'>South Goa</li>
```

I wand result **use quotes around the name of the city** inside the sawAll function like this

`<li ng-click="sawAll('North Goa');">North Goa</li>`

Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is this an AJAX problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: ajax and php are working good but problem is data show like <li ng-click='sawAll(North Goa);'>North Goa</li> this but i wand <li ng-click="selectbranchcity('North Goa');">North Goa</li> @NicoHaase

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. When the code currently prints `sawAll` in the loop and should print `selectbranchcity`, that sounds like something you should change in the code

Comment: @NicoHaase sry that my mistake i chnge the function name to check

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question. You still haven't told what you mean by "not working". If that is a problem of the proper markup being generated, it should be easy ti change the markup in the controller

Comment: @NicoHaase in i got function like ng-click='sawAll(North Goa);' but i wand ng-click="sawAll('North Goa');">

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it** - also, if you want to use quotes around the name of the city, why not add it to the markup when generating it? Isn't it obvious that they are not added randomly?

Comment: @NicoHaase i edit the question i am not well in English sry

Comment: "i want to use quotes around the name of the city" - why not add them where needed?

Comment: @NicoHaase thats my actual need

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i try to put single quotes in variable but i can't @NicoHaase

Comment: What do you mean by "i can't"? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `li` in controller like this

```
$result .= '<li ng-click="selectbranchcity(\'' . $list->city . '\');">' . $list->city . '</li>';
```

**Updated Solution**

you can use the htmlspecialchars() function as following.

```
public function selectPlaygrounds() {
    $data = $this->branchatm->getCitiesFromState($state);
    $result='';
    if($data){
        foreach($data as $list){
            $city = htmlspecialchars($list->city, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $result.="<li ng-click=\"sawAll('$city');\">$city</li>";
        }
    }
    $this->output
         ->set_content_type('application/json')
         ->set_output(json_encode($result));
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: the result show like <li ng-click="selectbranchcity('North" goa');="">North Goa</li>

Comment: i wand result like  <li ng-click="selectbranchcity('North Goa');">North Goa</li>  how i do for that

Answer (score 0):

To add quotes around the city name, you need to check which quote in your string needs to be escaped and which not. If this is your target string:

```php
<li ng-click="sawAll('North Goa');">North Goa</li>
```

...adding it could work like this:

```php
  $result .= "<li ng-click=\"sawAll('$list->city');\">$list->city</li>";
```

Comment: <li ng-click="selectbranchcity('South" goa');="" class="active">South Goa</li> result like this

Comment: What do you mean by "result like this"? The code from your snippet does not add any classes, so it can't result from the code you've shared